# How can I get an Integer from a Java Class into XML File (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to get an Integer from a Java class which I can use then in the XML file.

So this would be the get Code in the class file.

```
public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
```

how can I gain access to this number in the xml file?

Comment: I haven't touched Android for a while, but I don't think this is possible. What are you trying to do? You might have better luck approaching it differently.

Comment: Use the activity associated with the xml file to do this work.

Comment: If you edit the question to mention what exactly is the intention, people might be able to help better. You can get number from another xml or you can set the xml parameters from the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: not possible.

To get a number from a function similar to what you mentioned, you will need to execute java code which does not happen in compilation time.